# how to add to rows with duplicate key in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following pandas dataframe

```
   ID      Quantity     Key     Product   Code   decant
   0       10           12      HS        MT     123
   1       13           13      HS        LT     124
   2       15           13      HS        LT     124
   3       10           14      MS        PQ     145
   4       50           15      MS        PQ     146
```

My desired dataframe would be

```
  ID      Quantity     Key     Product   Code    decant
   0       10           12      HS        MT     123 
   1       28           13      HS        LT     124
   2       10           14      MS        PQ     145
   3       50           15      MS        PQ     146
```

I want add `Quantity` where `Key` is duplicated. I know we can do a groupby and add. But is there any simpler way to do it with `numpy`? Because I have other columns as well,so groupby will not be a suitable solution

Answer (score 2):

Try `groupby`:

```
print(df.groupby('Key',as_index=False).sum())
```

if want to fix `ID`:

```
df2=df.groupby('Key',as_index=False).sum()
df2['ID']=df2.index
print(df2)
```

Update try:

```
print(df.groupby(['Key','Product','Code'],as_index=False).sum())
```

If want to fix `ID`:

```
df2=df.groupby(['Key','Product','Code'],as_index=False).sum()
df2['ID']=df2.index
print(df2)
```

Comment: I have edited the question. I have other columns as well which are of type object.

Comment: @Neil Edited mine

Comment: I have 9 more numeric columns,in that case what would be the solution? Edited the question just for a reference

Comment: you can use `groupby().agg()` to aggregate different columns: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html